# How to properly serialize/deserialize java.time.DayOfWeek with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm working on an application that stores the day of an event. I'm using `java.time.DayOfWeek` to represent that day, and persisting it as a string (e.g. `MONDAY`, `WEDNESDAY`).

Jackson is serializing this type as a string, so the JSON representation looks like the value stored in the database. However, I want to serialize/deserialize it as the numeric value instead.

I tried using `@JsonFormat`, but the numeric shape available is based on the index, which is undesirable, as the value of `MONDAY` is `1`, not `0`.

Writing a custom serializer seems like the only solution here, but I have a feeling this issue has been tackled before somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the default getter and add a different method mapped to your `DayOfWeek` field. For the setter, you can make an additional setter that takes an `int` instead of the enum.

Here's an example implementation:

```
class MyDate {

    private DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.MONDAY;// DayOfWeek.of(LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek());

    @JsonIgnore
    public DayOfWeek getDow() {
        return dow;
    }

    public void setDow(int dow) {
        this.dow = DayOfWeek.of(dow + 1);
    }

    @JsonProperty("dow")
    public int getDayOfWeekNumber() {
        return dow.getValue() - 1; //0 for Monday
    }

    public void setDow(DayOfWeek dow) {
        this.dow = dow;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[dow=" + dow + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new MyDate()));
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"dow\":7}", MyDate.class));
    }
}
```

`DayOfWeek` doesn't have support for customizing the first day of the week or its index. That's why the above code is useing `+/- 1` to shift.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid any misunderstanding between layers and parts of app the best is to use `String` representation: `MONDAY`, `WEDNESDAY`, etc. If you want to serialise this `enum` as `int` any number is OK and as same good. On each layer you need to keep the information that `1` is `MONDAY` anyway. Whether it will be `0`, `1` or `10` it does not matter. In `Java` we have `Calendar.MONDAY` equal to `2`, `DayOfWeek.MONDAY` equal to `1` but also `WeekFields.ISO` where `MONDAY` is the first day and `WeekFields.SUNDAY_START` where `SUNDAY` is the first day of the week.

If you need to define `1` for `MONDAY` as a general idea for all `POJO` classes you need to register custom serialiser. Custom serialiser could look like below:

```
class DayOfWeekSerializer extends StdSerializer<DayOfWeek> {

    public DayOfWeekSerializer() {
        super(DayOfWeek.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(DayOfWeek value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeNumber(value.getValue());
    }
}
```

Custom deserialiser:

```
class DayOfWeekDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<DayOfWeek> {

    public DayOfWeekDeserializer() {
        super(DayOfWeek.class);
    }

    @Override
    public DayOfWeek deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return DayOfWeek.of(p.getIntValue());
    }
}
```

You can register them like below:

```
ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
    SimpleModule dayOfWeeModule = new SimpleModule("DayOfWeek module");
    dayOfWeeModule.addSerializer(DayOfWeek.class, new DayOfWeekSerializer());
    dayOfWeeModule.addDeserializer(DayOfWeek.class, new DayOfWeekDeserializer());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(dayOfWeeModule);
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    return mapper;
}
```

For below test `POJO class`:

```
class Days {

    private DayOfWeek monday = DayOfWeek.MONDAY;
    private DayOfWeek tuesday = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY;
    private DayOfWeek wednesday = DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY;
    private DayOfWeek thursday = DayOfWeek.THURSDAY;
    private DayOfWeek friday = DayOfWeek.FRIDAY;
    private DayOfWeek saturday = DayOfWeek.SATURDAY;
    private DayOfWeek sunday = DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;

    // getter, setters, toString
}
```

Example usage:
    ObjectMapper mapper = createObjectMapper();

```
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Days());
System.out.println(json);
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Days.class));
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "monday" : 1,
  "tuesday" : 2,
  "wednesday" : 3,
  "thursday" : 4,
  "friday" : 5,
  "saturday" : 6,
  "sunday" : 7
}
Days{monday=MONDAY, tuesday=TUESDAY, wednesday=WEDNESDAY, thursday=THURSDAY, friday=FRIDAY, saturday=SATURDAY, sunday=SUNDAY}
```